# Can't start repeating vibration after SCREEN_ON intent

Tags: android, android-vibration

I have an Service with endless vibrations, but vibrations stop when screen is turned off. After adding correct BroadcastReceiver, I noticed that I am unable to play repeating vibrations at all, after either screen on or off. Example simple code below:

```
//VibratingService class
Vibrator mVibrator;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            vibrate();
        }
    }, filter);

    vibrate();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mVibrator.cancel();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private void vibrate() {
    Log.d("TAG", "vibrate");
    mVibrator.vibrate(new long[] { 1000, 500 }, 0); //doesn't work
    //mVibrator.vibrate(new long[] { 1000, 500 }, -1); //works
}
```

What is strangest, vibrations work when *repeat* parameter in vibrate method is set to -1 (not repeating), but doesn't work when set to other values.

Any ideas, workarounds? Or maybe it just works on other phones? I runned it on Google Nexus and 4.1.2 Android

Edit:

After some tests I have determined that:

- vibrations will start correctly if they were stopped before screen went off (but not in onReceive - that seems too late)
- "system vibration" (for example when unlocking screen) lets vibrations start correctly with next screen on/off. Until next "break", and so on
- (edit2) - that is definitely connected to patterns - there is no such problem with vibrate(long millis) - all works fine

If I don't find any "normal" solution, I will just have to create my own Vibrator class probably...

Comment: it is possible that your mVibrator being fetched from from the context of the service is doesn't work on the broadcast. try to fetch it again in the onReceive (from Context context)

Comment: @njzk2 - I checked that, but it doesn't seems to be the case. It has something with vibrations being stopped "in pattern", it just seems I can't restart them correctly, only "system vibrations" can. Please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what causes that strange behaviour or if that happens on other phone models, but below is a code of my simple MyVibrator class that works after screen on and offs, should anyone else have this problem and no better solution is presented.

```
public class MyVibrator {

Vibrator mVibrator;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

boolean mIsVibrateOn;
private long mVibrateOnLength;
private long mVibrateOffLength;

private Runnable mVibrateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mIsVibrateOn) {
            mVibrator.vibrate(mVibrateOnLength);
            postVibrateRunnable(mVibrateOnLength + mVibrateOffLength);
        } else {
            mVibrator.cancel();
        }
    }
};

public MyVibrator(Context context) {
    mVibrator = (Vibrator) context
            .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
}

public void vibrate(long vibrateOn, long vibrateOff) {
    mVibrateOnLength = vibrateOn;
    mVibrateOffLength = vibrateOff;
    mIsVibrateOn = true;
    postVibrateRunnable(0);
}

public void stopVibrating() {
    mIsVibrateOn = false;
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mVibrateRunnable);
    mVibrator.cancel();
}

private void postVibrateRunnable(long delay) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mVibrateRunnable);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mVibrateRunnable, delay);
}
```

}

It has yet to be thoroughly tested, but so far it seems to be working fine. With some work it can be easily altered to use longer patterns